# EADDRINUSE in webpack on port 8080

Tags: reactjs, webpack

The command `webpack-dev-server --hot` is raising the EADDRINUSE for port 8080.

How can I change the ports used by webpack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`webpack-dev-server` CLI](https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html#webpack-dev-server-cli) supports a `--port` option.

Example:

```
webpack-dev-server --hot --port=8081
```

Answer (score 1):

This is due to port 8080 is in used already. So you can change your development server port which is not in used at the same time.

To change it using CLI,

```
webpack-dev-server --hot --port=8081
```

Or add **'port': '8081'** in your webpack JS file as follows,

```
'devServer': {
  ...
  'port': '8081',
  ...
}
```